# How to share the same instance with multiple interfaces in scoped service lifetime

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-6.0

Here is an example similar to the one on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-usage) page.

```cs
public interface IOperation
{
  string OperationId { get; }
}

public interface IScopedOperation1 : IOperation { }

public interface IScopedOperation2 : IOperation { }

public class DefaultOperation : IScopedOperation1, IScopedOperation2
{
   public string OperationId { get; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()[^4..];
}

public class OperationLogger
{
  private readonly IScopedOperation1 _scopedOperation1;
  private readonly IScopedOperation2 _scopedOperation2;

  public OperationLogger(
      IScopedOperation1 op1, IScopedOperation2 op2) =>
      (_scopedOperation1, _scopedOperation2) = (op1, op2);

  public void LogOperations()
  {
     Console.WriteLine($"Operation1: [ {_scopedOperation1.OperationId} ]");
     Console.WriteLine($"Operation2: [ {_scopedOperation2.OperationId} ]");
  }
}
```

And then if registered and called like this

```cs
using IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
        services
         .AddScoped<IScopedOperation1, DefaultOperation>()
         .AddScoped<IScopedOperation2, DefaultOperation>()
         .AddTransient<OperationLogger>())
    .Build();

host.Services.GetService<OperationLogger>().LogOperations();
```

Once `LogOperations` are called then `OperationId` is different for each injected instance.

Is there a way to share the same instance in the scoped service lifetime?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, register `DefaultOperation` as itself with scoped lifetime.

```
AddScoped<DefaultOperation>();
```

This way you will always have one object per scope.
Then, register interfaces to return that object.

```
services.AddScoped<IScopedOperation1>(sp => sp.GetService<DefaultOperation>());
services.AddScoped<IScopedOperation2>(sp => sp.GetService<DefaultOperation>());
```

Here, `sp` is of type `IServiceProvider`, through which you can call this very container and get any service.

Comment: Is the cast to interface required?